# Limit of series involving trig functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have the following series which i'm trying to check for convergence.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{sin5n+1}{-3n^2+1}$$

My thought process:

Since 5n can never be a multiple of either $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$, then it must be that $sin(5n) + 1$ must lie between 2 and 0 and so $  \frac{1}{-3n^2+1}< \frac{sin5n+1}{-3n^2+1}$ $<  \frac{2}{-3n^2+1}$.

Given that the limit of both the series as $ n\rightarrow \infty$ is 0 then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{sin5n+1}{-3n^2+1}$ must also be 0.

Is my thought process correct?

Comment: Exactly, you just used sandwich theorem

Comment: `Since 5n can never be a multiple of either ...` That's not necessary, and you don't actually use this. `must lie between 2 and 0 and so ...` That's correct, but it's not what you wrote next. Plus, you got the inequalities reversed there.

Comment: I don't get how the inequalities are reversed

Comment: @user140161 $\;\frac{2}{-3n^2+1} \le \frac{\sin{5n} \,+\, 1}{-3n^2+1} \le \frac{0}{-3n^2+1} = 0\;$

Comment: OH its because they're getting divided I see

Comment: $$-1+1 \le \sin(5n)+1 \le 1+1 $$
$$0 \le \sin(5n)+1 \le 2$$
Now, divide this by something "infinitely large" and you see what it will approach.